# How can I make CRON settings without Task Scheduler in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a problem when I use

> php artisan schedule:run

And that command returns

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

My server allows to call CRON above each 5 minutes.
So I think my server setting is the reason not to work schedule:run.
So I need to try CRON without Task Scheduler, and check if the CRON return correct response or not.

So please tell me how can I use CRON without Task Scheduler.
As information, I put my codes below.
These codes work correctly to send E-mail and make log when I use

> php artisan command:notice_expired_date

Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\NoticeExpiredDateCommand',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('command:notice_expired_date')
            ->daily()
            ->at(config('const.OPEN_TIME.FROM'))
            ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/schedule/notice_expired_date.log'));        
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }    
}
```

ExpiredDateNotification.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Ticket;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Notifications\ExpiredDateNotification;


class NoticeExpiredDateCommand extends Command
{
      protected $signature = 'command:notice_expired_date';

      protected $description = 'send email to user to notice the expired date of his tickets.';

      public function __construct()
        {
          parent::__construct();
        }

      public function handle()
        {
            $this->checkBefore1Week();
            Common::makeLog($this->getName());
        }

    protected function checkBefore1Week()
    {
        $from = Carbon::today()->copy()->addDays(7)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //ex. 2019-03-01 00:00:00
        $to = Carbon::tomorrow()->copy()->addDays(7)->subSecond()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $tickets = Ticket::whereBetween('expired_date', [$from, $to])->get();
        $noticing_users = [];
        foreach ($tickets as $i => $ticket) {
            $noticing_users[$i] = $ticket['user_id'];
        }

        if ($noticing_users != []):
            $users = User::find($noticing_users);
            foreach ($users as $user) :
                $user->notify(new ExpiredDateNotification($user, $expired_date = $from));
            endforeach;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Common.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class Common
{
    public static function makeLog($command_name)
    {
        $param = [
            'command_name' => $command_name,
        ];
        \Log::info('command executed', $param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by my self.
I wrote cron like this but not work.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, I write cron like this and it works.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /{project directory} && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The directory of php may depend on the server.

And about I type below on the terminal.

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

The ones place of the minutes of the time is 5, 
the command returns

> Running scheduled command

If the ones place of the minutes of the time is except of 5, it returns

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.